# Is there a workaround to enable auto-size with vega-lite facet charts?

Tags: powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I'm using vega-lite in deneb on Power BI.

I am creating a chart that has a single column of facets of horizontal bar charts. I also use a slicer to change the values on the y axis depending on what the user wants.

My issue is since the length of the y-axis values vary drastically, the bar charts are not consistently auto-sizing depending on what I select in the slicer. This leaves chunks of whitespace at the end of the graph:

e.g. when the 'long' category is selected, the chart fits within the border perfectly

[image]

But when 'short' is selected, there is extra whitespace

[image]

My aim is to have the bars (data container) stretch to fill the extent of the deneb visual, even if I select the 'Short' category.

[image: what I want to achieve]

I have played around with the various height and width options, but from my understanding of the vega-lite doco, auto-sizing does not work with facet charts.

I am therefore wondering if anyone has come up with a possible workaround?

Here's the code I have been working on (noting the dataset component here is normally just the Power BI columns)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "category": "Category1",
        "value": 90,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category2",
        "value": 20,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category3",
        "value": 30,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Super Very Long Category 11111111111",
        "value": 100,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Long"
      },
      {
        "category": "Super Very Long Category 22222222222",
        "value": 70,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Long"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category1",
        "value": 100,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category2",
        "value": 10,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category3",
        "value": 32,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Super Very Long Category 11111111111",
        "value": 90,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Long"
      },
      {
        "category": "Super Very Long Category 22222222222",
        "value": 30,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Long"
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet": {
    "field": "facet",
    "type": "ordinal"
  },
  "columns": 1,
  "spec": {
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
      "y": {
        "field": "category",
        "type": "ordinal"
      },
      "x": {
        "field": "value",
        "type": "quantitative"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT

What happens when I use an explicit "width" = 500 from Davide Bacci's suggestion:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you set an explicit width:

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "category": "Category1",
        "value": 90,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category2",
        "value": 20,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category3",
        "value": 30,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "a 11111111111",
        "value": 100,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Long"
      },
      {
        "category": "a 22222222222",
        "value": 70,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Long"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category1",
        "value": 100,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category2",
        "value": 10,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "Category3",
        "value": 32,
        "facet": "y",
        "slicer": "Short"
      },
      {
        "category": "a 11111111111",
        "value": 90,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Long"
      },
      {
        "category": "a 22222222222",
        "value": 30,
        "facet": "x",
        "slicer": "Long"
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet": {
    "field": "facet", 
    "type": "ordinal"
  },
  "columns": 1,
  "spec": { "width":500, 
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
      "y": {
        "field": "category",
        "type": "ordinal"
      },
      "x": {
        "field": "value",
        "type": "quantitative"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Davide, thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately setting an explicit width still results in the whitespace. My guess is because the data container remains the same width (500), but the whole container will move to the left of the deneb visual if the y axis labels are too small, resulting in the whitespace on the right. (I've added an image of what the visual with explicit width looks like into my question)